# How to toggle a column's visibility in a matrix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to toggle the visibility of a column ('TG3') so it can be toggled by a specific report item -

[The matrix looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gmvh.png)

It is set up so that 'Student' is toggled by 'Teacher', 'Teacher' is toggled by 'SectionDisplayName' and 'SectionDisplayName' is toggled by 'CourseDisplayName'. (It's a stepped report structure)

I want the 'TG3' column to be toggled by the 'Teacher' column. [This is what I've got in the TG3 column visibility settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CmEs.png)
However, this causes a scope [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJcaS.png)

Any help with how to get around this issue would be greatly appreciated, I've tried a lot of different approaches and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: I should add: I applied the exact same visibility property to the TG3 data cell of the matrix and it works, however for the header is just causes an error.

Comment: Is [Teacher1] the label or the data cell?

Comment: Hi Craig, Teacher1 is the data cell